# AWS Athena: Right function

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I would like to use the function `right` from AWS athena, but it does not seem to be supported.

How would I go about and trimming certain characters in Athena?

For example I would like to do `RIGHT('1313521521', 4)`

to get `1521`.  Unfortunately I would get something like

```
Queries of this type are not supported
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Athena uses Presto as SQL engine and it [does not have](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html) `right` function, but you can mimic it using `substr` and determining the staring position `greatest(length(str) - 3, 1)` - we need to start from 4th from last index, if string is too short - start from 1st index, cause Presto indexes starting from 1):

```sql
--sample data
with dataset(str) as (
    VALUES ('id1'),
    ('1313521521'),
    ('')
)

-- query
select substr(str, greatest(length(str) - 3, 1))
from dataset
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| id1 |
| 1521 |
|  |